# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE not printing anything

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus, dbms-output

When executing the following code, it just says the procedure is completed and doesn't print the infomation .

```
BEGIN
 dbms_output.put_line('This is my first program');
END;
/
```

When I execute the above code the compiler says , PL/SQL procedure successfully completed but doesn't print anything to the console . What can I do ?

Answer (score 19):

Switch the serveroutput on by

```
Set serveroutput on
```